# How to register an external device as a controller in Android

Tags: java, android, controller, device, tap

I've got a device which is sending signals to my Android app through the WiFi using its accelerometer and pressometer.
The aim is to convert the signals into tap and swipe gestures, leave my app in background, and use the device as the input source in other apps. (for example in fruit ninja, where a standard swipe in the middle of the screen will suffice for playing).
Of course, my app will stay in background and will function as a "bridge" from the device to the system.
To take it simple, tap and swipes will be performed in the center of the screen, so that the device might be the controller for some games like crossy roads or doodle jump.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need system permissions or *Ease of Access* workarounds to send the input to apps other than yours, but seeing that you can use a mouse, I'm sure your device will work as well.

Comment: what do you mean with "Ease of Access workarounds"? Ok that I can use a mouse, but how can I register as a controller, like the mouse does? Which are the services and classes I can use for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not an expert in programming for Android, but I know that if your controller maps the same as the Playstation 3 (Dualshock3) controller does, then you don't even need to do anything because newer Android versions (>4.0 ICS IIRC) come with native controller support. Otherwise look into the Android source code documentation about *Accessibility* (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) maybe this will help. Most of it is not well documented, mainly because of no real need.

Comment: Thanks, that will come in handy